# "Show Overlays" turn off when switching to Rendered, Anyway to change that?

Tags: 3d-view

I think I somehow turned it off (was it ever on though?)

I want the Show overlays to stay on when im switching between views. (Rendered\Preview\Solid)

Anyway I can do that?

Thanks in advance!